# Deleting certain bytes from a text file after reading them in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

i have written raw data (HEX characters) to text file.I want to retrieve mp3 information stored in the form of raw data in this text file after the text string MP3 start up till mp3 end.I have completed this operation but the problem now is the text contains many mp3 start and mp3end strings between which the mp3 characters are available.My program just extracts the  characters between the first mp3 start and mp3 end string.After extarcting this information i want to delete this information from the file so that my program can extract the next set of mp3 characters.Is there any efficient way to do it.I am working on vb.net

Comment: Instead of deleting the data, you could just continue your search. But to help here, it is necessary to see some code of how you find the regions.

Answer (score 0):

That depends.  If the file format allows items to be blanked out and left with a blank "page", then that would be the most efficient option.  However, if you must actually remove a section and shift up everything that comes after it, the only option is to rewrite the entire file.

Since you mentioned in the comments below that you do need to shift the rest of the file up to reduce the file size, your only option is to overwrite the entire file.  Without knowing more specifics about your code, it's hard to say how best to do that, but the simplest method would look something like this:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
' Modify and resize the bytes array
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath)
```

However, if the file is very large, you may not want to load the entire thing into memory all at once.  In that case, it would be better to read in one segment at a time, and append each segment to a separate new the file in a loop.  Then, when you are done copying all the desired data to the new file, you would need to rename it to overwrite the original file.  For instance, something like this:

```
Using input As New FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open)
    Using output As New FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create)
        Dim bytes(lengthOfMp3Record) As Byte
        Dim totalRead As Integer = 0
        Do
            totalRead = input.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            If (totalRead <> 0) AndAlso (KeepMp3record(bytes)) Then
                output.Write(bytes, 0, totalRead)
            End If
        Loop While totalRead <> 0
    End Using
End Using
File.Delete(inputFilePath)
File.Move(tempFilePath, inputFilePath)
```

Comment: @nico schertler-Thanks for the help and i achieved extracting all the mp3 characters also but i want to now delete the mp3 charcters with the strings to save the disk space because the file is increasing in size and as STEVEN DOGGART has mentioned i want to remove a section and shift up everything that comes after it.I dont want to replace the characters with spaces because that would not serve my purpose of saving the disk space.Is there any method or function i can look into to delete the characters

Comment: and i am really sorry but i dont have the authority to upload the code here sincere apologies because i know its hard to tell without the code but if you can just guide me i'll be grateful..thanks a lot

Comment: I also want help on finding the I.P address and the port number of an externally connected device through my program automatically can it be done?? My device sends all the mp3 information and i wanted to know the I.P address and port number from which it is sending the data.Is there any help available on this??

Comment: @mayurpatki I updated my answer to show some simplistic examples.  It's hard to be more specific without more details, but hopefully that's enough to point you in the right direction.  As far as the IP address and port goes, that all depends on the method of communication (e.g. socket, MSMQ, COM port, WCF).  In any case, it's always best to ask additional questions as entirely new question posts on stack overflow.

Comment: thanks a ton for your help i am successfully able to extract the information i need.I had to work my A** of to do that but appreciate your help and i'll keep it in mind about posting additional questions as new questions :D